# How can javascript submit form simplified

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, form-submit

I was wondering, how I could have Javascript send the "start rating" directly to my rating.php with the repeated javascript code.

Like the way it is, the codes are a little long even thought it works. 
I just need a simple, less code version for the javascript.

Can someone help me out with this. I tried a few thing, but they did not work for me.

So I send what I know works instead.

Javascript:

```
function mystar5() {
    var rate = document.getElementById("star5").value;
    $.post( "rating.php", { rating: rate}, function(output) {
        $("#output").html(output);
    })
};
function mystar4() {
    var rate = document.getElementById("star4").value;
    $.post( "rating.php", { rating: rate}, function(output) {
        $("#output").html(output);
    })
};
function mystar3() {
    var rate = document.getElementById("star3").value;
    $.post( "rating.php", { rating: rate}, function(output) {
        $("#output").html(output);
    })
};
function mystar2() {
    var rate = document.getElementById("star2").value;
    $.post( "rating.php", { rating: rate}, function(output) {
        $("#output").html(output);
    })
};
function mystar1() {
    var rate = document.getElementById("star1").value;
    $.post( "rating.php", { rating: rate}, function(output) {
        $("#output").html(output);
    })
};
```

Html:

```
<div id="dv1">
    <!-- star rating -->
    <h4>Simple Rating System</h4>

    <fieldset class="rating" onclick="mystar()">
        <input onclick="mystar5()" class="stars" type="radio" id="star5" name="rating" value="5" />
        <input onclick="mystar4()" class="stars" type="radio" id="star4" name="rating" value="4" />
        <input onclick="mystar3()" class="stars" type="radio" id="star3" name="rating" value="3" />
        <input onclick="mystar2()" class="stars" type="radio" id="star2" name="rating" value="2" />
        <input onclick="mystar1()" class="stars" type="radio" id="star1" name="rating" value="1" />
    </fieldset>
```

Comment: I think your script tag is malformed. "<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/j "

Comment: @Stah not really relevant

Answer (score 2):

One way

```
function myStars(num) {
    $.post("rating.php",
           {rating: num}, 
           function(output) { $("#output").html(output); }
    )
}
```

With

```
<input onclick="myStars(5);" class="stars" type="radio" id="star5" name="rating" />
<input onclick="myStars(4);" class="stars" type="radio" id="star4" name="rating" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Two choices:

Create a single function that is passed the rate via a parameter:

```
function mystars(rate) {
    $.post( "rating.php", { rating: rate}, function(output) {
        $("#output").html(output);
    })
};
```

usage:

```
<input onclick="mystars(5)" class="stars" type="radio" id="star5" name="rating" value="5" />
```

---

or create a function that is tied to your html (more useful if the parameter is longer, eg a paragraph of text) but less flexible

```
function mystars() {
    var rate = $(this).val()
    $.post( "rating.php", { rating: rate}, function(output) {
        $("#output").html(output);
    })
};
```

usage:

```
<input onclick="mystars()" class="stars" type="radio" id="star5" name="rating" value="5" />
```

I'd go with the first in this case if you like your `onclick` in the html.

---

Alternatively, separate your markup from your processing and add the click handler on load:

```
<input class="stars" type="radio" id="star5" name="rating" value="5" />
```

(note there's no `onclick`)

```
function mystars(rate) {
    $.post( "rating.php", { rating: rate}, function(output) {
        $("#output").html(output);
    })
};
$(function() {
    $(".stars").on("click", function() {
        mystars($(this).val());
    });
});
```